# SceneKit bone animation

Tags: xcode, animation, blender, scenekit

I'm new to SceneKit and trying to make a basic scene in the scene editor. I don't have any code written because I'm trying to do this all visually for now.

I have a tree that I made in Blender, and it has bones in it. I made a new scene and set the tree physics to dynamic and added a turbulence field, but the bones don't seem to do anything even with the turbulence field added.

Can someone point me in the right direction? All I'm trying to do is make the tree blow with the wind.

Here's a screenshot of the editor, I can provide the DAE file if needed.

[image]

Comment: You might need huge values for the force in the field.